# Using the Mediator pattern with services and repositories in a Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, mediator

I have a design with controllers, services and repositories and I'm in doubt how the mediator pattern fits into the design. The examples I've seen use the mediator pattern is with only controllers and repositories. My middle layer "Services" makes my head spin of how it should be implemented in my case.

I will try to explain why I have this design in the first place.

E.g. I have a UserController with the method CreateUser(). The controller routes the request to the UserService. The UserServices CreateUserAsync() are responsible for validating the request, creating the user in the database (using UserRepository) and sending emails etc. It might use several services and repositories.

Another could be DashboardController with the method GetDashboard(). It uses the GetDashboardAsync() method on the DashboardService to gather information from different services and repositories.

This way the repositories methods can be reused in different services. It even returns IQueryable collections so that services can filter even more on the queries to i.e. select less data or using the count for e.g. dashboard queries.

So do I implement the mediator pattern from the controllers to the services or the services to the repositories?

My thought is to implement it from services to repositories, as this is here I have a lot of DI.

Also another thought is that it might be a cleaner pattern if from services, I only went from services to repositories. But sometimes I'm using services in services. I'm not sure if this will be a problem for implementing the mediator pattern.

Comment: Your architecture is not bad. It is good enough for many use cases and small applications. But when your application grows up, when appears many side effects (mails, sms, domain events, integration events, messages stored in queues etc.) you need more readable architecture: clean architecture. There are many articles and courses about that e.g at pluralsight. Mediator is one of the patterns that are used to improve architecture. You can also read about cqrs pattern. In my opinion you need to write code in traditional way. Also check Microsoft free ebook, and github project e-shop on containers

Comment: @zolty13 I'm confused. Your comment does not answer my question, it raises more questions. What do you mean is the traditional way of writing code? Why is it not a clean architecture? Also I don't think I will have problems with mails, sms and stuff, its application services I can inject anywhere. Please be more precise if you have any idea of how to improve it.

Comment: It comes from experience and books. It is difficult to explain in one answer. Questions bear more questions. Your architecture is good enough and controller service and repository is a traditional way of writing web code

Comment: Clean architecture is just a name